# Unable to fetch and display data from database in ASP.NET core web application using Razor Pages

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a table `dbo.purchased`, and I have a Razor page called `Purchaseditems` which is supposed to fetch data from that table and display in a tabular format. At present the page loads a blank table.

I have checked the data types are matching with the database table and the reader function.

I am new to ASP.NET Core and Razor Pages.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code:

`Purchaseditems.cshtml.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace PCERM.Pages.FOAL_Management_System.Purchased_List
{
    public class PurchaseditemsModel : PageModel
    {
        public List<purchasedinfo> purchaselist = new List<purchasedinfo>();

        public void OnGet()
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionstring = "Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=PCERM;Integrated Security=True";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    string sql = "SELECT * FROM purchased ORDER BY itemid2";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                purchasedinfo purchaseinfo = new purchasedinfo();
                                purchaseinfo.itemid2 = reader.GetInt32(0);
                                purchaseinfo.serno2 = reader.GetInt32(1);
                                purchaseinfo.sername2 = reader.GetString(2);
                                purchaseinfo.qty2 = reader.GetInt32(3);
                                purchaseinfo.unit2 = reader.GetString(4);
                                purchaseinfo.lastprice2 = reader.GetInt32(5);
                                purchaseinfo.vendorname2 = reader.GetString(6);
                                purchaseinfo.department2 = reader.GetString(7);
                                purchaseinfo.section2 = reader.GetString(8);
                                purchaseinfo.category2 = reader.GetInt32(9);
                                purchaseinfo.pccategory2 = reader.GetString(10);
                                purchaseinfo.invoicevalue2 = reader.GetInt32(11);
                                purchaseinfo.invoicedate2 = reader.GetDateTime(12).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                                purchaseinfo.actualitem2 = reader.GetString(13);
                                purchaseinfo.actualrate2 = reader.GetInt32(14);
                                purchaseinfo.actualquantity2 = reader.GetInt32(15);
                                purchaseinfo.actualprice2 = reader.GetInt32(16);
                                purchaseinfo.pricediff2 = reader.GetInt32(17);
                                purchaseinfo.actualvendor2 = reader.GetString(18);
                                purchaseinfo.deliverystatus2 = reader.GetString(19);
                                purchaseinfo.invoicefilename2 = reader.GetString(20);
                                purchaseinfo.imagefilename2 = reader.GetString(21);

                                purchaselist.Add(purchaseinfo);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public class purchasedinfo
    {
        public int itemid2 { get; set; }
        public int serno2 { get; set; }
        public string sername2 { get; set; } = "";
        public int qty2 { get; set; }
        public string unit2 { get; set; } = "";
        public int lastprice2 { get; set; }
        public string vendorname2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string department2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string section2 { get; set; } = "";
        public int category2 { get; set; }
        public string pccategory2 { get; set; } = "";
        public int invoicevalue2 { get; set; }
        public string invoicedate2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string actualitem2 { get; set; } = "";
        public int actualrate2 { get; set; }
        public int actualquantity2 { get; set; }
        public int actualprice2 { get; set; }
        public int pricediff2 { get; set; }
        public string actualvendor2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string deliverystatus2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string invoicefilename2 { get; set; } = "";
        public string imagefilename2 { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

`Purchaseditems.cshtml`:

```
@page

@model PCERM.Pages.FOAL_Management_System.Purchased_List.PurchaseditemsModel

@{
}
<br>
<h1 class=" my-3 text-center">List of Purchased Items</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Item ID</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Serial No</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Serial Description</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Original Quantity</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Last Purchased Price</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Suggested Vendor</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Department</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Section</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Category</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Permanent/ Consumable</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Invoice Value</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Invoice Date</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Item Purchased</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Actual Rate</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Quantity Purchased</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Actual Price</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Price Difference</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Purchased From</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Delivery Status</th>
            <th style="text-align:center ; vertical-align:middle">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.purchaselist)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.itemid2</td>
                <td>@item.serno2</td>
                <td>@item.sername2</td>
                <td>@item.qty2</td>
                <td>@item.unit2</td>
                <td>@item.lastprice2</td>
                <td>@item.vendorname2</td>
                <td>@item.department2</td>
                <td>@item.section2</td>
                <td>@item.category2</td>
                <td>@item.pccategory2</td>
                <td>@item.invoicevalue2</td>
                <td>@item.invoicedate2</td>
                <td>@item.actualitem2</td>
                <td>@item.actualrate2</td>
                <td>@item.actualquantity2</td>
                <td>@item.actualprice2</td>
                <td>@item.pricediff2</td>
                <td>@item.actualvendor2</td>
                <td>@item.deliverystatus2</td>
                <td style ="white-space:nowrap">
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Upload Invoice</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Upload Image</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">View Invoice</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">View Image</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add Transaction Details</a> @*Edit/Update*@
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Remove Item</a>                @*Delete*@
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Table in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[purchased] 
(
    [itemid2]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [serno2]           INT           NOT NULL,
    [sername2]         VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [qty2]             INT           NOT NULL,
    [unit2]            VARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [lastprice2]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [vendorname2]      VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [department2]      VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [section2]         VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [category2]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [pccategory2]      VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [invoicevalue2]    INT           NOT NULL,
    [invoicedate2]     DATETIME      DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
    [actualitem2]      VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [actualrate2]      INT           NOT NULL,
    [actualqty2]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [actualprice2]     INT           NOT NULL,
    [pricediff2]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [actualvendor2]    VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [deliverystatus2]  VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [invoicefilename2] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [imagefilename2]   VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([itemid2] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Step through your with the debugger and fine out where it's going wrong

Comment: If you are using the visual studio, there is a tab in the bottom of the window named output where you can see the output of your `Console.WriteLine`. Check if there are any errors. Another way is to remove the try catch block and see if there is any error popping up when you access the page.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys...The issue was the use of incorrect namespace viz Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead of System.Data.SqlClient;